# MongoDB: Grouping elements of a nested array in-place

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Wondering how to use the aggregation pipeline to group the `procedures` arrays in-place by their `type`.

So turning this:

```json
[
    {
        "airport": "MSP",
        "country": "USA",
        "procedures": [
            {
                "name": "ABC1",
                "type": "DEP"
            },
            {
                "name": "JKL2",
                "type": "ARR"
            },
            {
                "name": "LMN3",
                "type": "DEP"
            },
            {
                "name": "PQR4",
                "type": "ARR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "airport": "CMH",
        "country": "USA",
        "procedures": [
            {
                "name": "GHI4",
                "type": "ARR"
            },
            {
                "name": "RST3",
                "type": "ARR"
            },
            {
                "name": "TUV7",
                "type": "DEP"
            },
            {
                "name": "XYZ4",
                "type": "ARR"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

into this:

```json
[
    {
        "airport": "MSP",
        "country": "USA",
        "procedures": {
            "ARR": [
                {
                    "name": "JKL2",
                    "type": "ARR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PQR4",
                    "type": "ARR"
                }
            ],
            "DEP": [
                {
                    "name": "ABC1",
                    "type": "DEP"
                },
                {
                    "name": "LMN3",
                    "type": "DEP"
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "airport": "CMH",
        "country": "USA",
        "procedures": {
            "ARR": [
                {
                    "name": "GHI4",
                    "type": "ARR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "RST3",
                    "type": "ARR"
                },

                {
                    "name": "XYZ4",
                    "type": "ARR"
                }
            ],
            "DEP": [
                {
                    "name": "TUV7",
                    "type": "DEP"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I've gotten as far as

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$procedures"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$procedures.type",
      procedures: {
        $push: "$procedures"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

but it loses the `airport` structures and mixes the data all together:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "DEP",
    "procedures": [
      {
        "name": "ABC1",
        "type": "DEP"
      },
      {
        "name": "LMN3",
        "type": "DEP"
      },
      {
        "name": "TUV7",
        "type": "DEP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "ARR",
    "procedures": [
      {
        "name": "JKL2",
        "type": "ARR"
      },
      {
        "name": "PQR4",
        "type": "ARR"
      },
      {
        "name": "GHI4",
        "type": "ARR"
      },
      {
        "name": "RST3",
        "type": "ARR"
      },
      {
        "name": "XYZ4",
        "type": "ARR"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 2nd stage: `$group` by `airport` and `procedures.type`.
2. 3rd stage: `$group` by `airport`, add objects with `k` and `v` fields into the `procedures` array.
3. Last stage: `$project`, Decorate the output document by converting the `procedures` array into a key-value pair via the `$arrayToObject` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$procedures"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        type: "$procedures.type",
        airport: "$airport"
      },
      country: {
        $first: "$country"
      },
      procedures: {
        $push: "$procedures"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$_id.airport",
      country: {
        $first: "$country"
      },
      procedures: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.type",
          v: "$procedures"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      airport: "$_id",
      country: "$country",
      procedures: {
        $arrayToObject: "$procedures"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/31QM_-LRPXl)